# with keyword does not compile when used with generic type

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-10.0

When using the C# `with` keyword with an actual struct type it works exactly as expected, however when dealing with some generic type `T` that is constrained to be a `struct` it results in a compiler error.

Is this a bug or intended behaviour, and if so, what's stopping the generic approach from working?

```cs
public interface ICountSomething
{
    public int Counter { get; }
}

public struct ActualStruct : ICountSomething
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public int Counter { get; init; }
}

public class Blah<T>
    where T : struct, ICountSomething
{
    public T DoSomethingWithGenericConstrainedToStruct(T input)
    {
        // Does not compile
        return input with
        {
            Counter = input.Counter + 1,
        };
    }

    public ActualStruct DoSomethingWithActualStruct(ActualStruct input)
    {
        // Compiles ok
        return input with
        {
            Counter = input.Counter + 1,
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add "where T : struct" to the method, too! I get a different error message (stating that it's a preview feature). But I am still on an old c# version, so it might work for you.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid C#, it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'T'`.

Comment: I also see a red line under "Blah<T>". Maybe something is wrong there too, although I don't see anything wrong at first glance.

Comment: @Joost00719 That's just because I have multiple types in this file

Comment: @JonasH I've updated my question with additional generic constraints, my real world usage would constrain the generic type with an interface that exposes properties that could be used as part of the `with` block.

Comment: @SteveWilford: i just got a different compiler error that you cannot assign a value to Counter since its readonly.

Comment: Your interface property would need a init/set for your example to make any sense. It would not be able to set the Counter if it is get-only.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a problem with Rider, the project does in fact build, it's just flagging up in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues - `Counter` on the interface is readonly so it can't be modified and/or used inside `with` expression. Change the interface to:

```cs
public interface ICountSomething
{
    public int Counter { get; init; }
}
```

The `with` itself seems to be Rider/Resharper issue, the code should compile just fine (after adding `init` to the interface) - checked at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChGKaBOACgCJAeDcBB9zgJQBuRswDMAAgCWeDDCgAzAIZgYEgJIBhCPgwBlCAFsYGABYyA5owDejCfYkVJMjBO275E6xIsmh0vCkMfwBfRjCmBicJAGcMXDBXAEFEnCUAGz14nESJEA13WQNjM0sbOwdolgAGCQA5JWMvHz9Y1oiHR2dZNx1ZT29fYICg0PDRKMlqCQAhdKVTAB4AFQA+CvsAd1N5NWW82OzEtAK+/SMTczwrBlsGTuj9gBEIYsvLAHUg0wBxGDx5FIwNo8HEoEoZDBCMtXkcMOx9jIAA44DACDZeCadB4AdgCKNcm2+GM6d2x5N6HigEgAvPjUQA6QpyakkCQ0NAkhwhET3bkTEJAA). Submitted the bug for Rider.

Answer (score 0):

Since `T` is a generic type, the compiler does not know which type is going to be used for T.
It knows it is a struct, but it cannot tell which properties `struct T` has.

The `with` keyword has to know which properties it can set. Since there is no way the compiler can possibly know which properties there are in `T`, you cannot use `with`.

Edit: this works: notice the `init` on the property of the interface.

```csharp
public interface ICountSomething
{
    public int Counter { get; init; }
}

public struct ActualStruct : ICountSomething
{
    public string Name { get; init; }

    public int Counter { get; init; }
}

public class Blah<T>
    where T : struct, ICountSomething
{
    public T DoSomethingWithGenericConstrainedToStruct(T input)
    {
        // Compiles ok
        return input with
        {
            Counter = input.Counter + 1,
        };
    }

    public ActualStruct DoSomethingWithActualStruct(ActualStruct input)
    {
        // Compiles ok
        return input with
        {
            Counter = input.Counter + 1,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying about the compiler not knowing, but if the generic constraint includes an interface then I don't really see why the compiler _couldn't_ know which properties are available.

Comment: Maybe you can set the generic constraint to struct, IInterface. I haven't tried it.